# Creating database file one directory above current

Tags: python, sqlite

In PHP, To refer to a higher directory I would use '../../test'; 
How would I do it in Python?

In this case, I'm using SQLite to create a database file.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('../data/test.db')
```

However; it says 'unable to open database file' which I'm considering as a directory access error. How do I refer to higher directory in Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might try this:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(os.path.realpath('../data/test.db'))
```

Comment: Love this solution - Thank you sir!

Answer (score 2):

You need to find absolute path to your database file, using [`os.path.abspath`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) and [`os.path.dirname`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname). Then pass the absolute path to `sqlite3.connect`.

First (internal) `os.path.dirname` will give you current file's directory, second `os.path.dirname` will give you parent directory of current file's directory.

```
from os.path import join, dirname, abspath
db_path = join(dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__))), 'data/test.db')
sqlite3.connect(db_path)
```

Comment: Use `from . import .` please for shorter code like `from os.path import dirname, abspath; dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))`

Comment: Please don't scare me away from Python!

Comment: @OliverK It is normal practice in Python to specify the path explicitly.

Comment: Both great solutions, but I think @gview 's is more simplistic. Thanks!