# how to reach a file in the active directory with python

Tags: python, sqlite, directory

My Database and my python script are in the same folder but I can't reach my Database by using

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('VCbase.db')
```

so I use

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('C:/Users/Stagiaire/Desktop/Ketrika/VCbase.db')
```

It works but I must change my code if i want to run my code in an other PC, I Want to know if there is a way to reach my DataBase without de adress.

Thank you

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784897/creating-database-file-one-directory-above-current) post, it fixes your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you run your code. Probably if you use a text editor, you are running the code from some folders above the script and the database, that's why it can't find it.
If you want to make this always work, you can just execute this code from the terminal by navigating to the folder of the script and database and typing "python script_name.py", or you can modify your code with the OS library to make this always get the absolute path of the file